# Android create multidimensional array and get value

Tags: java, arrays

My first language is PHP :) and newbie to Android and Java. I am trying to understand Array system in Java as it is quite different than PHP. So far understood Java has two different types of arrays *(correct me if I am wrong)*. `arr[]` and `ArrayList<>` Also unlike PHP in Java we have to define `datatype`for the array.

I am making a simple quiz app (without database) just to learn. For that I want to create a multidimensional array containing question, answer and options like this.

```
{
    {
        question,
        {option1, option2, option 3, ...}
        answer
    }

    {
        question,
        {option1, option2, option 3, ...}
        answer
    }

    {
        question,
        {option1, option2, option 3, ...}
        answer
    }

    ...
}
```

I know basics of creating a multidimensional array using `arr[][] = {}` but I don't know how I can add another array for options to get the similar result as above.

### Update

So I want to populate list in this way.

[image]

Comment: You can make you own Model class, which will have question, options list and answer, then make arraylist of that model class

Comment: @AbdulKawee thanks for the suggestion.As I said, I am newbie so example code would be highly appreciated and helpful to understand.

Comment: Do you want structure like this i.e
question list i.e q1,q2,q3,q4
answer list i.e a1,a2,a3,a4
you want both list in one list from which you get both ?

Comment: An ArrayList is not an array. ArrayList is a class. Don't use arrays in general. And don't use multi-dimensional arrays to store various things: define a class Question (as you would in PHP, BTW), and use a List<Question>. Any Java introductory book, or the Java tutorial, describes what a class is. It's a fundamental concept. You need to learn the language and do some research.

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan In Java I am not so much sure which approach is better but I want to loop through Array to populate questions to create form with radio buttons for the question. Than when user submit I will compare with the answer.

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan please have a look the reference image I have added

Comment: Updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//You can do it like this, add model class

```
  public class Quizmodel {

String mAnswer = new String();
String mQuestion = new String();
List<String> mOptions = new ArrayList<>();
public String getmQuestion() {
        return mQuestion;
    }

    public void setmQuestion(String mQuestion) {
        this.mQuestion = mQuestion;
    }

public String getmAnswer() {
        return mAnswer;
    }

    public void setmAnswer(String mAnswer) {
        this.mAnswer= mAnswer;
    }





    public List<String> getmOptions() {
        return mOptions;
    }

    public void setmOptions(List<String> mOptions) {
        this.mOptions = mOptions;
    }
    }
```

//Set Values for model class, in main class;

```
   List<Quizmodel> mQuizList = new ArrayList<>();
    String mQuestion = new String();
    mQuestion = "Ask Question Here ?";
    List<String> mOptionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    mOptionsList.add("A1");
    mOptionsList.add("A2");
    mOptionsList.add("A3");

    Quizmodel mModel = new Quizmodel();
    mModel.setmQuestion(mQuestion);
    mModel.setmOptions(mOptionsList);
     mModel.setmAnswer("A2");

    mQuizList.add(mModel);

    //String m = "";
    for (int ind = 0; ind < mQuizList.size(); ind++) {
        System.out.println(mQuizList.get(ind).getmQuestion());
        //  Log.v("response",mQuizList.get(ind).getmQuestion());
        for (int index = 0; index < mQuizList.get(ind).getmAnswers().size(); index++) {
            System.out.print(mQuizList.get(ind).mAnswers.get(index) + " ");
           // m = m + mQuizList.get(ind).mAnswers.get(index) + " ";
        }
System.out.println(mQuizList.get(ind).getmAnswer());
    }
```

//Just follow step you will get desired result.
//Added sample Input and Output.

> **Sample Output**
>
> Ask Question Here ?

Answer Options

> A1 A2 A3
>
> A2

//I hope it will bring ease.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by making your own model class as

```
public class MyCustomModel {

String question;
List<String> options;
String answer;

public MyCustomModel(String question, List<String> options, String answer){
 this.question = question;
 this.options = options;
 this.answer = answer;
}

 // getter and setter methods here

}
```

And then simply make an `array list`

```
private ArrayList<MyCustomModel> myData;
```

And then add data to List

```
myData.add(new MyCustomModel("question 1",myListOfOptions, "answer"));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. please have a look the reference image I have added on question.

Comment: Yes i have checked it, and this code can solve this problem,

Comment: Okay. one more question. Should I set `myData` in activity where I want to use array? Sorry if silly one but I am new and learning it.

Comment: please check the edited answer, and accept if it helped you